# Vue Components and AJAX loaded HTML content

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have A Vue component which is basically a shorthand for complex HTML markup.

On initial load, Everything works fine.

I am using AJAX to load more of these components onto the page, The problem is that this component, after being loaded with AJAX, doesn't want to get compiled into HTML I only get the un-rendered Vue component like below:

`<component><slot>content</slot></component>`

I have looked at Vue.compile() and the render function but cannot figure out how to get this working or how to re-render? the components.

Hope that makes sense, Can anyone shed some light on what I should be doing here?

Comment: Can we see some code? Not quite sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should let your data drive the view.

In other words, let's assume you have the following html:

```
<div id="app">
    <component></component>

    <!-- the following ones are inserted via ajax -->
    <component></component>
    <component></component>
</div>
```

and js:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'bar',
  }
})
```

You are probably making the ajax request and inserting manually the `<component></component>` into the html. That's not the way you should work with Vuejs.

The way you let your data drive the view is, well, creating the needed data:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'bar',
    components: [
        {}, //component related data
        ...
    ]
  },

  components: {
    component,
  },

  ajaxRequest() {
    //this should push into your components array
    // example:
    $.ajax().done(function(data) {
        this.components.push(data);
    })
  }
})
```

In this code, I've added a new array (`components`) to the `data` that will store the components I want to render in my view. When I fetch components via ajax I add them to this array. Now, if I change the html to:

```
<div id="app">
    <component v-for="component in components" data="component">
    </component>
</div>
```

whenever the `components` array is updated, Vue will automatically add them to the view.

Comment: you are spot on, I've been going about this the wrong way, thanks for the explanation, should be able to get it working now!

Answer (score 1):

Using the functions "extend" and "$mount":

```js
axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
        template: response.data
    })

    var compiled = new MyComponent().$mount()

    $('#div').append(compiled.$el)
})
```