# Vue v-on:click not working on Ajax content

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new in Vue, and I have component (id="apartments"), in which I am getting content from another resources/views file, the code which I have used for adding html is:

```
 plansHtml = '<a href="{{ $plans[0]['href'] }}" v-on:click="testfunction();"></a>';//This is the html which I am getting from Ajax, and in this html I have used v-on:click
 activePlanContainer.html(plansHtml);
```

And the code in my Js file is:

```
var appApartments = new Vue({
    el: '#apartments',
    methods: {
        testfunction: function() {
            console.log('Test function called');
        }
    }
});
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, I have also tried v-on:click-native="testfunction();" but this also didn't worked.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try v-on:click.prevent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue Components and AJAX loaded HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499917/vue-components-and-ajax-loaded-html-content)

Comment: I have tried both above solutions and both not working.

Comment: try:
@click.native="testfunction(); for me this was working

Comment: You need to make sure your Vue code executes after you inject the Ajaxed code or it will never be parsed by Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have two question here

- Nothing in your `<a></a>` tag from your code
- If you use native javaScript or jQuery to create Dom element, vue can't listen it(this means that the syntax of vue cannot be used.)

or your can provide more code for us to solve your problem

Comment: May be some compliation is required after adding html?

Comment: You need to use vue create DOM element , maybe you can provide all code that about createit